# Need help using a google script across all google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Need help using a google script across all google spreadsheets without copying script to each sheet. I've converted the script project to a cloud-managed platform and enabled all the APIs that I think are required.

I've deployed the script as add on and I see it on the add ons menu in sheets but I can't call my functions, etc.

Comment: Please be more specific, maybe share your script

Comment: currently, I have them spread out in 3 different script projects but I want to combine them. The scripts are for my invoicing, timekeeping, scheduling, database and some engineering tools. My plan is to start with consolidating all the scattered scripts and sheets into minimal as possible. Then lastly, make an app with app maker  if possible

Comment: You could just use a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries).  It has been said that this may slow down your script but in my case I've never seen that problem and they're very  easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Within one project you can have several different script files (You can create them by going to File>New>Script file). I suggest you distribute your functions and your logic across them the way you most prefer. Afterwards, any of those functions can be accessed by any of the other files declared in the project, so you should have no issue on calling them from i.e. your Add-on.

Additionally, you can use [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries). To do so:

1. Create a new Project (which will serve as a library). It may have multiple *gs* files, with multiple functions.
2. From the *guest* script, the one that will use the library, go to Resources>Libraries. There, insert your library project's id, and the identifier that will be used (variable name) to reference it. For the example below, I have set it to be `MyMathLibrary` (see example usage in *Invoicing.gs*).

#### Example project:

[image: Example project]

- Project link: https://script.google.com/d/1kNeHHS7M19ILwcbbootMfZFNtg0NdE27WtkElXFBgOVR6haUUKPYqOBL/edit?usp=sharing
- Library link:
  https://script.google.com/d/12x33E1q3Uk2dgx5SfVTllVel8PeHcudQ-Czwhnu7aJPU5-tFpICuEcMM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: is there any way you can post that project on here so i can look at each file and copy script if needed?

Comment: @lucaswilliams I have edited the answer with a bit more information and links to the project. Cheers

Comment: Can you create variables in library and call?

Comment: @lucaswilliams Yes, you can see in my example (*Invoicing.gs*) a call to a function declared in the library. You may also declare global variables in the library that may be accessed the same way.

Comment: Could you give me a quick example of a global variable for my database sheet in my admin platform spreadsheet.

Comment: @lucaswilliams no worries, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Im adding a menu to my sheets and im getting a "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.newMenu() from this context." I used the same exact script on another sheet but it doesnt work on the current sheet?                                                                           
  function onOpen(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Send New Approved Invoice", functionName: "SendSheetAsPDF"});
  ss.addMenu("Email Invoice", menuEntries);
};

Comment: @lucaswilliams the `newMenu()` function must be executed from an `onOpen()` trigger function (it cannot be manually called either, using the GAS IDE). See [onOpen(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene). Also if you have different questions consider opening another, separate question here on stackoverflow. Have a nice day!